# How to do a POST request from SAPUI5 controller to Java Servlet?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, sapui5

I have created a dynamic web project with a Tomcat 8.5 Server and then I created an index.html that do start my first view (a simple form for login). When I click the button for login start function onPress:

```
     onPress : function() {
          var user = this.getView().byId("userInput").getValue();
          var pwd = this.getView().byId("passwordInput").getValue();
          var request = {
                un : user,
                pw : pwd
            };
          $.post("LoginServlet", request, function() {
            alert("Ciao");
          });
      }
```

I want to pass user and pwd to this servlet (LoginServlet)

```
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {

    try {    
        UserBean user = new UserBean();
        user.setUserName(request.getParameter("un"));
        user.setPassword(request.getParameter("pw"));

        user = UserDAO.login(user);

        /*if (user.isValid()) {

            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
            session.setAttribute("currentSessionUser", user);
            response.sendRedirect("userLogged.jsp"); // logged-in page
        }else
            response.sendRedirect("invalidLogin.jsp"); // error page*/
    } catch (Throwable theException) {
        System.out.println(theException);
    }
  }
}
```

The error I am getting is:

> 404 Not Found. Description: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists. Message: /LOGIN_RACMET_UI5_DynamicWebProject/LoginServlet

I need that the frontend is developed in SAPUI5, so I can't use JSP, PHP, etc.

The project is structured like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aTBp.png)

When i do the call this is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4HG7.png)

Comment: 404 Not Found. Description: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists. Message: /LOGIN_RACMET_UI5_DynamicWebProject/LoginServlet

Comment: Have you tried to execute this URL : **http://localhost:8080/LOGIN_RACMET_UI5_DynamicWebProject/LoginServlet** on a REST Client? To check, whether it's really working.

Comment: Yeah, this is right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve it. It's wrong the url

```
$.post("LOGIN_RACMET_UI5_DynamicWebProject/LoginServlet", request, function() {
        alert("Ciao");
      });
```

This is right